# Can I use an exposed water pipe as a reference only?

Tags: grounding, earth

The outlets in my working space are unearthed, but there is an exposed copper bit of heating pipe that appears earthed (there is 230 V between it and the outlet). Now, after some research here I've gathered that it is not a good idea to use this pipe to hack together an earthed socket, at least not for a direct safety earth connection. In particular, if there's a fault and the plumbing network has some resistance to earth, it could be energized.

However, what if I make a socket whose earth prong is connected to that pipe *through a suitably large resistor*? I'm thinking that way at least any connected devices could use that earth as a reference, or to prevent floating.

- Would this be of any use? Do any devices actually use earth in this way?
- Does the resistor actually provide any/enough safety? In the case where there is a fault and the plumbing network is floating, it would still have 230 V on it. But if you touch it this voltage will drop as soon as any current starts flowing through the resistor. On the other hand, this may prevent fuses or the GFCI from tripping.
- If this idea won't work, is there any way I can benefit from this pipe to make my lab better?

I live in an older house in the Netherlands, insofar as that matters.

Comment: use: Sure. For example, antistatic mats and wristbands and such have a high-ohmic path to earth. They don't need to dump a lot of current, only enough so that things don't build up drastic static charges.

Answer (score 2):

The earth wire is not only used for potential reference, but also as safety wire to carry fault current from live back to neutral as the earth and neutral are connected together somewhere in your electrical system. So:

No, even if the pipe was earthed properly, it would be unsafe to use it as path for fault current, as it is not designed for it.

No, resistor will completely bypass the safety of earthing as it must have as low resistance as possible to safely carry fault current.

Just don't connect the pipe to anything. Leave the electrical work to professional licenced electricians as most likely you don't have the expertise and permits to legally and safely do electrical installations.

Comment: "No, even if the pipe was earthed properly, it would be unsafe to use it as path for fault current, as it is not designed for it." I already concluded this in my question. I am in no way intending to use it for fault current. My only concern is not making any fault (that could happen whether I do this or not) any worse.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify, the current unearthed socket does accept earthed plugs and I do use it with devices that have one of those, so it's not a situation of installing a bad safety measure to be able to use more "dangerous" devices.

Comment: Many devices use earth for safety, others use earth for functionality. Many devices with earthed plug say they must only be connected to an earthed socket. If you have e.g. a desktop computer with standard ATX power supply, I recommend not to use it on un-earthed socket. The metal case will float capacitively at 120 VAC (half mains voltage). That does not feel nice and can cause damage when connecting to other equipment.

Comment: While I understand it's not advisable to do so, it's simply not practical to not use those devices at all, and since those old sockets are still quite common here, I'm assuming the risk is deemed acceptable (we do all have GFCI's). But regarding the floating computer, is that not exactly what my idea would solve?